# How can I filter certain data based on user input in bar chart?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a CVS file similar to:

| Country | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | A | 3 |
| Canada | B | 4 |
| Canada | C | 5 |
| USA | A | 3 |
| USA | C | 2 |
| Mexico | B | 5 |
| Japan | A | 6 |
| Japan | B | 3 |
| Japan | C | 2 |

I would like to create a bar chart which has the Countries on the X axis and the Values on the Y axis. I would also like to have a side panel dropdown filter with the Categories listed and only show the data which corresponds to the selected category. So if the A category was selected the Value of the Canada bare would be 3. I am having a lot of trouble apply filters to my X and Y axis. This is what I have so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df=read.csv("name.cvs")

ui <- fluidPage(
   
    titlePanel("Title"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Category", "Select Category", choices = df$Category)
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("chart")
        )
    ) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$chart <- renderPlotly({
           
        p <- plot_ly(       
            x = df$Country,
            y = df$VALUE,
            name = "Important Data",
            type = "bar" ,          
        )            
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can probably tell I am new to R shiny and I am really struggling with this project. Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to dropdown value using `input$Category` and a simple filtering using base R `subset` or `dplyr::filter` should be enough.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Title"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Category", "Select Category", choices = df$Category)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("chart")
    )
  ) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderPlotly({
    sub_df <- subset(df, Category == input$Category)
    p <- plot_ly(       
      x = sub_df$Country,
      y = sub_df$Value,
      name = "Important Data",
      type = "bar" ,          
    )            
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! is there any way to add multiple filters when creating the subset? Say I have another column called category2 and I would like to filter based off of that.  Something like sub_df <- subset(df, Category == input$Category AND Category2 = input$Category2)

Comment: Yes, you can use `sub_df <- subset(df, Category == input$Category & Category2 == input$Category2)`